# JQuery Click function This H5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code I need to add a click function to display some text,

```js
$('.membre').click(function() {
  $(this, 'h5').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="membre">
  <div class="annuPersoPhoto"><img></div>
  <div class="annuPersoTxt">
    <div class="persoTxtUp">
      <h4>Name</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="persoTxtDown">
      <h5>Text</h5>
      <h5 style="display:none;">Phone</h5>
      <h5 style="display:none;">Email</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `this` and `'h5'` are the wrong way around: `$('h5', this)`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Agreed with @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tax76szr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.membre').click(function() {
  $('h5', this).css('display', 'block');
});
```

You had `h5` and `this` the wrong way.

This should work.

Comment: Instead of answering try to close it as a TYPO mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your `jQuery` is somewhat correct. However the way you select your "h5" elements are not the right way to do it. Try giving this a try:

```
$('.membre').click(function() {
    $(this).find('h5').show();
});
```

As a side-note it would be a better idea to move the "display: none" into a CSS file, if it's a larger project.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Instead of answering try to close it as a TYPO mistake

Comment: I'm just sending a code that works out for sure which I find would be the best way around it, nothing else. Have a nice day :-)

Comment: As well as same kind of answer already given before you posted and deleted as well due to heavy down-vote:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/53278003/4248328

Comment: OP's code will work in all situation if he swap `h5` and `this`.:- https://jsfiddle.net/tax76szr/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback though @AlivetoDie :-)